# Typescript: Generic over Map<K,V> value type

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

Here's a simplified version of the problem. I'm trying to create a function that will operate generically on an interface with `Map` properties.

```
interface Data {
  map1: Map<string, number>;
  map2: Map<string, string>;
}

const d: Data = {
  map1: new Map(),
  map2: new Map(),
};

// This doesn't work
public dataSet<T extends keyof Data, V extends Data[T]... (need help here)>(d: data, dataKey: T, key: string, val: V) {
  d[dataKey].set(key, val);
}

// Ideally, called like:
dataSet(d, 'map1', 'alpha', 3);
dataSet(d, 'map2', 'beta', 'charlie');
```

The type definition of `V` is currently the `Map` type rather than the `Map`'s value type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some conditional types to infer the key and value types of your Maps. You'll run into a type issue when calling `set` because TS is inferring `d[dataKey]` as a `Map<string, number> | Map<string, string>`. But we know what we're doing here so we can safely add a `@ts-expect-error` line.

I tested this on TS v4.1.5 on the playground.

```js
interface Data {
  map1: Map<string, number>;
  map2: Map<string, string>;
}

const d: Data = {
  map1: new Map(),
  map2: new Map(),
};

type GetKey<M extends Map<any, any>> = M extends Map<infer K, any> ? K : never;
type GetValue<M extends Map<any, any>> = M extends Map<any, infer V> ? V : never;

function dataSet<K extends keyof Data>(d: Data, dataKey: K, key: GetKey<Data[K]>, val: GetValue<Data[K]>) {
  // @ts-expect-error
  d[dataKey].set(key, val);
}

// This now enforces the types correctly.
dataSet(d, 'map1', 'alpha', 3);
dataSet(d, 'map2', 'beta', 'charlie');
dataSet(d, 'map2', 'foo', true); // Errors as expected.
```

Here's a [link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#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) as well.

Answer (score 1):

How about using objects instead of Maps ?

```
interface Data {
  map1: {
    [K: string]: number
  };
  map2: {
    [K: string]: string
  };
}

const d: Data = {
  map1: {},
  map2: {},
};

function dataSet<T extends keyof Data, V extends Data[T][string]>(d: Data, dataKey: T, key: string, val: V) {
  d[dataKey][key] = val;
}


// works:
dataSet(d, 'map1', 'alpha', 3);
dataSet(d, 'map2', 'beta', 'charlie');

// Errors
dataSet(d, 'map1', 'alpha', 'charlice');
dataSet(d, 'map2', 'beta', 3);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=31&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUM5AWzgAcBGALh3wOQG0BpKgZzClAHMBdKkAV0IAjaDQC+AbhrESAJip5a9JslbsQ3Fm05jJo3LgQB7EK2QATKukzIAvNQLTKOUQBoppOc7cT9MPiAQwYGNzDDgAZQgwAB4AFWQIAA9IEDNmZABrCABPQxg0MJdkADUE5IhU9Ks4OliuOlVOLgA+AAoLAswiszCGHKpYoqzszTUOIoA3OAAbKmKASntzOh7MPuz64a5bZCnp3X1cAHoj5ABJMwgZ6eyihGuIM2Rp4CyKXFWIqPaigHJHX5-GYkAAWcEByAAzPNJJ9ImAfsh-h4Ib9hJhUQgwVAXhBfjD9CdkABRKBQQxQZgfMLwxHI8io4FgzHYl5IfGwmnfMx-aQyVHo8FFaGSIA)

Comment: Great! I'm using Typescript 4.1 where this doesn't work, but thanks to your playground link I see that this'll work on TS >= 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

It is possible to do with help of inference. You should infer whole data structure.

```js
interface Dictionary {
  map1: Map<string, number>;
  map2: Map<string, string>;
}

const d: Dictionary = {
  map1: new Map(),
  map2: new Map(),
};

const dataSet = <
  MapKey,
  MapValue,
  HashMapKey extends string,
  HashMap extends Record<HashMapKey, Map<MapKey, MapValue>>,
  >(hashMap: HashMap, dataKey: HashMapKey, key: MapKey, val: MapValue) =>
  hashMap[dataKey].set(key, val);

// Ideally, called like:
dataSet(d, 'map1', 'alpha', 2) // ok
dataSet(d, 'map1', 'alpha', 'str') // expected error

dataSet(d, 'map2', 'beta', 'charlie');
dataSet(d, 'map2', 'beta', 4); // expected error
```

`HashMapKey` - infers `map1` and `map2`

`HashMap` - infers whole data structure (argument)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCLAWYB7EcoCeyA3gFDLIC2cADgIwBcyAsrQDwDOYUoA5gDTIQAV0oAjaAD4A3OSq0ATE1Y1O3PoK48QvGaQC+pUglxdkAEybpMOPIWQBeEnOr0mICAHcWtABQBKfhdFdy8fGgCg-VljUzALODA4AGUIeKc2ORUAaQgCIIoVADU4ABthCALkAAk4DgALHLzkCAAPSBBzDmQtDTlahpUW9ohO7oAlCBMoczYBxtpc-PC2JuXisorJSSrJX3q6hZomeZVBc0S4JZPDtcEAazzlRbzBADcy55oS8oh-R0kcgOg1oAG0LkklgBdAB0HDSvkeyw+pX8MQA9OjkABJcwQMqlZYIAkQczIUrAR4MUgQlII8yCADkrjojKZZRoBzZyAU-0xyGw9xpl1SYF8DOQzNorPZpU5cG5jK0jL5WLaNCmkDJ0Cg2CgRlpovFTNcCkVEiSioQBygFIgKtkhvpJsU5rSCsEABY0ch+erNaSWlBdVAgA)

If you are interested in function argument inference, you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It's not ideal because of the explicit redefinition of `string | number` in `Value extends string | number`. Is there any way that could be inferred from the value types of the maps automatically?

Comment: @BrainCore I made an update